Where does geckodriver store logs?
I can't find it in  /var/log  dirrectory
The error:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1

Tried
find /var/log -name '*geckodriver*'

Nothing find.
Run as:
   options = Options()
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  driver=webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

OS version:
cat /etc/os-release
Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS


try 'find / .... -name 'gecko.log' (you may need to 'sudo' that), also, it may be somewhere in mozilla land logs ....
